# Where is salt key defined in openldap conf file?

Tags: java, encode, openldap, ssha

I am updaing ldap userPassword using SHA-1 hashing from java code. How can I retrieve the salt key from ldap server or password which I can use to generate SSHA password.

```
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
       md.update(password.getBytes("UTF8"));
 //      Base64 base64 = new Base64();
       byte[] hash = md.digest();
       String sshaPassword = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(hash));
       return "{SSHA}" + sshaPassword;
```

Comment: You can't. It isn't in there.

Comment: Hi EJP, Thanks for you reply. so is there any wayto create SSHA encoded password in my java code.